# Plotting multiple scatter plots of multiple years in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib

I have a dataframe that looks like:

```
Date            Faculty         Target        Avg
2012-01-01       Arts             80           60
2012-01-01       Science          70           60
2012-02-01       Arts             91           89
2012-02-01       Gym              80           89
.
.
2012-07-01       Arts             83           67
2012-07-01       Science          72           67
2012-08-01       Arts             81           83
2012-08-01       Science          70           83
```

I want to plot all **Faculty** on a single scatter plot with each of their respective **Target** values (Y-Axis) and **Avg** values (X-Axis).

I'm trying to use (pseudo code) a scatterplot like:

```
ax1 = data.plot(kind='scatter', x='Avg', y='Target(Arts)', color='r', label='Arts')    
ax2 = data.plot(kind='scatter', x='Avg', y='Target(Science)', color='g', ax=ax1, label='Science') 
ax3 = data.plot(kind='scatter', x='Avg', y='Target(Gym)', color='b', ax=ax1, label='Gym')
```

I'd like all Faculties (there are 28 of them total) on the same plot for every Target value (marked by different colors) but there are too many to manually enter with `loc` (or at least I'd like to avoid this). I can't use `iloc` to count by index because each number of Faculty counts is different on each date.

Is there a simple way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can `groupby` the `Faculty`, and iterate over the groups, plotting each one:

```
g = df.groupby('Faculty')

for faculty, data in g:
    plt.scatter(data['Avg'], data['Target'], label=faculty)

plt.xlabel('Avg')
plt.ylabel('Target')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

[image]